# Wie durchgängig muss der Konjunktiv in einem Satz verwendet werden?

Tags: usage, subjunctive, verb-usage

Offenbar muss der Konjunktiv nicht durchgängig im Satz verwendet, wenn es innerhalb des Satzes auch um Dinge geht, bei denen klar ist, dass sie schlicht wahr sind. Z. B.

> **[Satz 1:]** Hätte Gandalf den Ring, um den es in "Herr der Ringe"
> *geht* (nicht: *ginge*), für sich behalten, wäre die Geschichte ganz anders verlaufen.

"Ginge" klingt zumindest für mein Sprachverständnis in diesem Satz offensichtlich falsch. In anderen Fällen ist mir allerdings unklar, wie durchgängig der Konjunktiv im Satz verwendet werden *muss* -- es also ansonsten grammatikalisch ein klarer Fehler wäre -- wenn es um Dinge geht, die sich zwar in einem fiktiven Szenario abspielen, aber eigentlich allgemein wahr sind. Etwa im Satz:

> **[Satz 2:]** Nehmen wir an, es gäbe eine Zwillingserde, und auf dieser Erde würde
> jemand feststellen, dass "2+2=4" *ist/sei*, dann wären die
> Zwillingsmenschen auf der Zwillingserde ähnlich mathematisch begabt
> wie wir.

Dass 2+2=4 ist, ist ja offensichtlich eine Wahrheit, auch innerhalb dieses fiktiven Szenarios. Darf man in diesem Fall "ist" verwenden, wie im obigen Satz "geht", oder ist das inkorrekt und was ist in diesem Fall die Regel? Dann nochmal ein ähnlicher Fall, bei dem es um Folgerichtigkeit in einem fiktiven Szenario geht:

> **[Satz 3:]** Nehmen wir an, es gäbe eine Zwillingserde und dort hätte jemand den
> Jackpott im Lotto gewonnen, weil er 6 Richtige angekreuzt *hat/hätte*.

Es scheint zwar möglich, hier auch "hätte" anzugeben, ist aber wegen der Dopplung sprachlich nicht so schön, weshalb ich mich frage, ob hier auch "hat" richtig wäre, weil die betreffende Person ja gar nicht im Lotto gewonnen haben könnte, ohne 6 Richtige zu haben, also es in diesem fiktiven Szenario wiederum eine allgemeine Wahrheit *ist* (oder: *wäre*??). Dann ein letzter Fall, wenn zwar eine fiktive Position angeführt wird, aber die Konsequenzen wahr wären:

> **[Satz 4:]** Nehmen wir an, jemand würde glauben, man müsste einen IQ von 400
> aufweisen, um an der Universität studieren zu dürfen. Dies hätte aber
> wohl zur Folge, dass es auf der Erde niemanden mehr gäbe, der
> studieren *darf/dürfte*.

Kann man hier "darf" schreiben, weil es folgerichtig wahr ist? Wäre für eine fundierte Antwort sehr dankbar, da meine eigene Recherche hierzu bislang nicht so ergiebig war.

Comment: Wenn ein Muttersprachler so eine Frage stellt, hagelt es Upvotes. Bei einem Lerner hätte man gefragt: Welche Anstrengungen wurden denn unternommen, um die Frage selbst zu klären? Dann Close Vote, je nach sprachlicher Korrektheit auch Downvote.

Comment: In den Büchern die ich nachgeschlagen habe steht meistens nur, dass der Konjunktiv durchgängig verwendet wird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Satz 1) Da hat Dein Sprachverständnis auch völlig recht. In dem Fall wird ein realer Sachverhalt beschrieben und deshalb ist der Indikativ, ähem, indiziert.

Satz 2) Der Konjunktiv ist hier richtig, allerdings nicht, weil es hier um etwas Reales oder Irreales geht, sondern weil indirekte Rede im Konjunktiv steht: Ich sage: "2 plus 2 ist 4". Wenn Du das hörst, dann kannst Du jemand  anderem erzählen: "Er sagte, 2 plus 2 sei 4".

Satz 3) Wie Du richtig vermutest, ist hier der Indikativ dem Konjunktiv vorzuziehen, weil das über Satz 2 Gesagte - die indirekte Rede - eben nicht greift und deshalb unumstößliche Tatsachen auch im Indikativ stehen können.

Satz 4) Grundsätzlich steht immer der ganze Relativsatz im gleichen Modus. "der studieren darf/dürfte" ist aber kein Relativsatz, sondern nur Teil eines solchen. Es bestimmt lediglich das "niemand(en)" näher. Deshalb ist hier der Konjunktiv korrekt.

@Horstfuchs: das stimmt zwar, aber Deine durchklingende Frustration, daß nicht näher erklärt wird, was "durchgängig" genau bedeutet, kann ich verstehen. Ich hoffe, das mit meiner Erklärung verständlicher gemacht zu haben.